# Call ActionA from ActionB then proceed with ActionB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controllers

I think I misunderstand something about MVC. I'm trying to do the following:

```
public class ControllerA : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // do code

        // perform action on ControllerB - something like:
        // RedirectToAction("Action", "ControllerB");

        // CARRY ON with more code
    }
}

public class ControllerB : Controller
{
    public void Action()
    {
        // do code
    }
}
```

Obviously `RedirectToAction("Action", "ControllerB");` isn't working. So how do I do it? I guess I could have all controllers that need to use Action() inherit from ControllerB but that feels a really bad way to do it. Please help!

Comment: care to elaborate on what `//do code` is doing in ControllerB? Maybe you need RenderAction in view code?

Comment: Just any sort of reused business logic that you would want to use in multiple controllers.

Comment: Then you should pull that business logic into a separate class so you can use it in multiple controllers.

Comment: So I shouldn't just instantiate a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return the ActionResult from RedirectToAction()

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "ControllerB");
```

is what you need to do if you want RedirectToAction to actually redirect to an action.  After you clarified what "isn't working" means to you I think you should just have all controllers inherit from a base.  That is a pretty standard approach.

```
public class ControllerA : ControllerB
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // do code

        Action();

        // CARRY ON with more code
    }
}

public class ControllerB : Controller
{
    public void Action()
    {
        // do code
    }
}
```

Comment: How does that work if Index() is supposed to be returning a view and Action() is void? Index() won't be able to continue after we RedirectToAction.

Comment: Well right Index() won't continue, you are exiting the method.  I don't understand your question because Action() has no view therefore you have nothing to redirect too.

Comment: That's because I don't want Action() to return a view, I want it to do 'something' and then continue on with the action that called it.

Comment: The just call the action like a method.  `var b = new ControllerB(); b.Action();`

Comment: Somebody downvoted this?  I'd like to know why or if there is an alternative.

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't originally answer the question. Perhaps update your answer so I can upvote.

Comment: @ajbeaven - Sorry, I assumed from the phrase "it isn't working. So how do I do it" you meant how do I redirect.

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer. I've never before seen an instance of a controller used like that - is it common practice?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the controller you are currently executing is an instance of the class so you would need to make an instance of controller B to be able to execute anything on it, so what you are trying to do there just won't really work without a hack.

I think however there is 2 methods to better get the results i think you are after:

1) Make a 'ControllerBase' class and have all controllers inherit from it instead of from 'Controller' then any shared code you can add into the base class (as a static method perhaps) and then all controllers can access it as a member nice and easy.

2) As MVC will make a straight up DLL you can add in new classes as you need, eg add a new project folder like 'Globals' add a new class file called 'Funcs' and there you have a static lib that you can access from anywhere, Funcs.SendEmail(); etc

If i'm off the mark ok! happy coding anyway heh

Answer (score 0):

I have injected controllers with a factory method from the controller factory as a delegate (Func CreateController), and used that to create sub-controllers, such as in this circumstance.  There's plenty of ways to accomplish your goal, but I think that might be quick way to get what you want working.